# Bootstrap Navbar Change on Scroll Up or Down

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I want the navbar when scrolling up or down replace for a svg file.

As you can see i'm using. top to change de navbar, but i need it to change on scroll up and down without making top > 56 like this.

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    $(document).ready(function() {
      var navpos = $("#navbar_scroll").offset().top;
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        let windowpos = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (windowpos >= navpos) {
          $("#navbar_scroll").addClass('navbar_style_2');
          $("#navbar_scroll").removeClass('navbar_style_3');
          console.log("up");
        } else {
          $("#navbar_scroll").addClass('navbar_style_3');
          $("#navbar_scroll").removeClass('navbar_style_2');
          console.log("down");
        }
      })
    });

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <nav id="navbar_scroll" class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm fixed-top navbar-inverse navbar_style">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand hidden-md-up" href="#"><img src="tps.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="width: 27px; height: 27px;"></a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active " href="tu_pasion_click">1</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link " href="tu_voz_click">2</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">3</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">4</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">5</a>
        </div>
        <a class="navbar-brand hidden-sm-down" href="#"><img src="tps.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="width: 27px; height: 27px;"></a>
        <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">6</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">7</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">8</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">9</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">10</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: I updated my answer. I'm guessing your #navbar_scroll may be in the wrong place. If you provide the HTML we might be better able to address your need.

Comment: done, check my update please

Comment: You should edit the question, rather than provide updates as an "answer." But yeah #navbar_scroll should be placed on the container that you want to make the change. Otherwise you're just getting the offset of the nav bar

Comment: im sorry, as you can see im new making questions, right now im trying to make it work and somethings it work but not always, i dont know why. Can you make it a demo?

Comment: Click on the "DEMO" link in my answer

Comment: If any of these answers helped or solved your issue, please upvote and/or mark as answered.

Comment: Hey Joe. I cant solve the problem. I need when I scroll up or down. Change the nav bar to a svg figure. When the scroll is static. Stay with the nav bar.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding what you are trying to accomplish. Would you be able to link to something that is close to what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer and see if that is more inline with what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Issue

In order to detect whether a user is actively scrolling we need to check to see whether how long since the last scroll event. Since we only want to fire the function the minimum number of times required we can use $.debounce.

## Solution

The snippet demonstrates `$.debounce` by Ben Alman which detects the user's scroll. More accurately it detects when the event hasn't happened after a set amount of time and then fires the function. This will allow the function to fire once after the set number of milliseconds

`$.debounce(delay, at_begin, callback)`

Note, that at_begin is false by default:

> (Boolean) Optional, defaults to false.  If at_begin is false or unspecified, callback will only be executed `delay` milliseconds after the last debounced-function call.  If at_begin is true, callback will be executed only at the first debounced-function call.  (After the throttled-function has not been called for `delay` milliseconds, the internal counter is reset)

If at_begins is `true`, then the function will fire at the first function call (after the set delay).

If `at_begins` is `false`, then the function will fire once only after the last event was called (after the set delay)

[Read more about $.debounce and $.throttle plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/)

```js
(function(window,undefined){
  '$:nomunge'; 
  var $ = window.jQuery || window.Cowboy || ( window.Cowboy = {} ),

      jq_throttle;

  $.throttle = jq_throttle = function( delay, no_trailing, callback, debounce_mode ) {

    var timeout_id,

        last_exec = 0;

    if ( typeof no_trailing !== 'boolean' ) {
      debounce_mode = callback;
      callback = no_trailing;
      no_trailing = undefined;
    }

    function wrapper() {
      var that = this,
          elapsed = +new Date() - last_exec,
          args = arguments;

      function exec() {
        last_exec = +new Date();
        callback.apply( that, args );
      };

      function clear() {
        timeout_id = undefined;
      };

      if ( debounce_mode && !timeout_id ) {
        exec();
      }

      timeout_id && clearTimeout( timeout_id );

      if ( debounce_mode === undefined && elapsed > delay ) {
        exec();

      } else if ( no_trailing !== true ) {

        timeout_id = setTimeout( debounce_mode ? clear : exec, debounce_mode === undefined ? delay - elapsed : delay );
      }
    };

    if ( $.guid ) {
      wrapper.guid = callback.guid = callback.guid || $.guid++;
    }

    return wrapper;
  };

  $.debounce = function( delay, at_begin, callback ) {
    return callback === undefined
      ? jq_throttle( delay, at_begin, false )
    : jq_throttle( delay, callback, at_begin !== false );
  };

})(this);

//Here is the implementation of $.debounce
$(window).scroll($.debounce(0, true, function(){
  $('nav').addClass('hide');
}, 250));

$(window).scroll($.debounce( 250, function(){
  $('nav').removeClass('hide');
} ) );
```

```css
body{
  height: 6000px;
}

.svg{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}

.mt-100{
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.hide{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <img class="svg" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/262726/pattern.svg" width="100%"/>
 <nav class="fixed-top navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
<div class="container mt-100"><h1>Scroll Down</h1></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Updated to provide some more comments and a pen.

Comment: hello joe, im checking it right now, give a few minutes to see it

Comment: hey joe, i think im not giving you the exact requirement, maybe with a example well solve the problem. I want my navbar have the behavior like www.marca.com (mobile version), as you can see, the navbar change on scroll (that change for me, will be a svg figure), when no scroll (behave like normal navbar). Do you understand now? thank you

Comment: Ok I've created a couple examples. The first responds similar to the marca site in which the svg is shown on scroll down and nav bar is returned on scroll up. The second applies the .debounce and adds the image when the user is actively scrolling but then returns the nav menu when the user stops. Hopefully, one of these gets you closer. Let me know and I'll update my answer.  

[Option 1](https://codepen.io/jbanegas/pen/8e21fe266d5f368815e74d22e6ade80f?editors=0110)  or  [Option 2](https://codepen.io/jbanegas/pen/4b21b41292edaf94ba751090a9ef6dcc?editors=1011)

Comment: Hello Joe. Let me check it. Thank you for you patience

Comment: Hello Joe. The asnwer is the option 2, thats what i wanted, i need to make it some changes but thats ok. Thank you so much !

Comment: Great! I'll update my answer to reflect that option and then if you'd please mark it as the accepted answer I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm.... The green checkmark isn't showing on my end. Can you double check that you clicked it? Much appreciated.

Comment: of course. this is the message i recieve "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Answer (score 0):

This will works for you

```
var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
window.onscroll = function() {
    if(document.body.scrollTop > scrollTop) {
        // Down Scrolling
        scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
    }
    else {
        // SCrolling Up
        scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is small example which shows you how to capture an event when you scroll:

```js
var navpos = $(".container").offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  let windowpos = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (windowpos >= navpos) {
    console.log("You scrolled!"); // your code comes here.
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var navpos = $("#navbar_scroll").offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    let windowpos = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (windowpos >= navpos) {
      $("#navbar_scroll").addClass('navbar_style_2');
      $("#navbar_scroll").removeClass('navbar_style_3');
      console.log("up");
    } else {
      $("#navbar_scroll").addClass('navbar_style_3');
      $("#navbar_scroll").removeClass('navbar_style_2');
      console.log("down");
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<nav id="navbar_scroll" class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm fixed-top navbar-inverse navbar_style">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand hidden-md-up" href="#"><img src="tps.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="width: 27px; height: 27px;"></a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active " href="tu_pasion_click">1</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link " href="tu_voz_click">2</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">3</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">4</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">5</a>
    </div>
    <a class="navbar-brand hidden-sm-down" href="#"><img src="tps.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="width: 27px; height: 27px;"></a>
    <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">6</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">7</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">8</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">9</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">10</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```